# Posting data to Google sheets results in "required authentication credential" error

Tags: ionic-framework, google-sheets, google-api, google-oauth, ionic3

I am trying to post values to google spreadsheet from my ionic 3 application. But i am getting the following error.

> {"_body":"{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 401,\n    \"message\": \"Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.

How to get Oauth token from login response. In login response,
 i am getting the following,

```
"{"familyName":"test","givenName":"test","displayName":"test ","email":"test","userId":"1157365464646546546"}"
```

So, how to get the oauth response from the user's login?

Comment: In order to access any google api your applicaiton needs to be registered with Google via the Google developer console.   Also sheets data is private data there for you need to have permissions to access it using oauth2.  I am not an Iconic dev but these links may help    https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing  http://blog.ionic.io/google-oauth-changes/

Comment: @DalmTo Yeah i registered my application in dev console and i got the client id and oauth token from console. Will i get access token in response for each user login?

Comment: You got a client id and client secret from console you did not get an auth token.   To get an access token you will need to request access of a user.  I have a Google development for beginners series that may help http://www.daimto.com/google-development-beginners/